# How start new activity through intent from android SearchView widget query submit

Tags: android, searchview

This is main activity of my app. From main activity i can navigate to item list activity by selecting any of categories from RecyclerView list. Also i need to go to the same item list activity by searching item name directly in android SearchView widget in the tool bar. I wrote the code for searchview like this

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.app_bar_item, menu);

        /*final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);*/

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        if (null != searchView)
        {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                    .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        }

        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
            {
                Log.d("TAG","You queried for="+query); // Here it prints correct query input. but doesnot starting the new activity.
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ItemListActivity.class);
                intent3.putExtra("FetchType","ItemSearch");
                intent3.putExtra("CatId",query);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


/*And i accept both the navigations from main activty(By selecting Category list item, or by inputing hint in search widget) in my list item activity like:*/

    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null)
        {
            fetch_hint = extras.getString("FetchHint"); /* Fetch hint is Category name selected or Searchquery input.*/
            fetch_type = extras.getString("FetchType");  /* if activity start from category item selection, Fetch type is set as ByCat, If it is from searchview set as ItemSearch*/
        }
```

It is work fine for By category search, But wont for searchview. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

startActivity is not called. Application context can't work to start activity.

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ItemListActivity.class);
            intent3.putExtra("FetchType","ItemSearch");
            intent3.putExtra("CatId",query);
startActivity(intent3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like below:

```
/*final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);*/

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    if (null != searchView)
    {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    }

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {
            Log.d("TAG","You queried for="+query); // Here it prints correct query input. but doesnot starting the new activity.
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ItemListActivity.class);
            intent3.putExtra("FetchType","ItemSearch");
            intent3.putExtra("CatId",query);
            startActivity(intent3);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this code

```
         Intent intent3 = new Intent(YourActivityName.this,ItemListActivity.class);
         // instead of getApplicationContext use yourActivityName.this
        intent3.putExtra("FetchType","ItemSearch");
        intent3.putExtra("CatId",query);
        startActivity(intent3); <------------ here is you are missing this      
                                               line
```